# if statement in asp.net ASP.DataList vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In Classic ASP I was able to display a section break based on state. I have an SQL table with menu items, columns:(ListOrder(int),BeginUrl(varchar(20),ShowDate(varchar(20),EndUrl(varchar(20),Section(varchar(20)) BeginURL,ShowDate,EndUrl concatenate to create the link. Section is state (WA,OR,ID). 
In classic I created a var nLevel set to "" then proceed to loop through the RS.

```
Do While NOT menuRS.EOF
   If menuRS.Fields("Section") <> nLevel Then
       Response.Write("<br><br>" & menuRS.Fields("Section"))
       nLevel = menuRS.Fields("Section")
   End If    
   If menuRS.Fields("Display") = 0 Then
       Response.Write("<br>"& menuRS.Fields("BeginUrl")&menuRS.Fields("ShowDate")&menuRS.Fields("EndUrl")) & VbCrLf
   End If
   menuRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Which would give me (roughly)

```
WA
<a href="stuff">[date]</a>
<a href="stuff">[date]</a>
OR
<a href="stuff">[date]</a>
<a href="stuff">[date]</a>
ID
<a href="stuff">[date]</a>
```

Trying to duplicate that in .Net using a DataList, ItemTemplate, and ASP:Label of course using VB, is giving me fits on the 'section' break.
I have the main menu items looping out. Just failing on the Section Break.

```
<asp:DataList ID="MenuList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="NwccMenuList">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="SectionBreak" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# If(Eval("Section") <> Me.nLevel) Then (Eval("Section") Me.nLevel= Eval("Section") End If%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="BeginUrlLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("MenuUrl") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NwccMenuList" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:nwcctanningConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ([BeginUrl]+[ShowDate]+[EndUrl]) AS MenuUrl, Section 
    FROM [Menu] WHERE ([Display] = 0) ORDER BY [Section] DESC, [ListOrder]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Display" 
            Type="Byte" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Not sure the nLevel variable (in codefile) is reachable or not cannot get past the If statement!
I appreciate any pointers or where I went wrong!

Comment: You'll need a Repeater and a lot of extra code in the ItemDataBound event or a custom renderer to do that with WebForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you want to replace one dinosaur code with another ancient code. OK, Let's do it in ASP.NET way. First, `asp:DataList` is not the best choice because it renders table. Use the simplest databound control like `asp:Repeater`. This is a sample code which do the work *declarativelly*.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMenu" runat="server" DataSource="NwccMenuList">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrSection" Text='<%#Eval("Section") %>'></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="sqlSubmenu">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MenuUrl") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("MenuUrl") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <%-- Note that a child datasource is inside parent ItemTemplate --%>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlSubmenu" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:nwcctanningConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT ([BeginUrl]+[ShowDate]+[EndUrl]) AS MenuUrl 
                FROM [Menu] WHERE ([Display] = 0 and Section=@section) ORDER BY [ListOrder]">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <%-- literal control from parent ItemTemplate --%>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ltrSection" Name="section" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NwccMenuList" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:nwcctanningConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT distinct Section FROM [Menu] WHERE ([Display] = 0) ORDER BY [Section] DESC">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Display"
            Type="Byte" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Again, this approach is more than 10 year old.

Comment: There were a couple if gotchas in there, cleaned them up. I appreciate your assistance. Had to turn the asp:Literal into an asp:Label ('PropertyName must be set to a valid property name of the control named 'ltrSection' in ControlParameter 'Section') and had to ad ID to the DataSource fileds in the repeaters.
Once again I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: `asp:Literal` doesn't render any HTML markup. `PropertyName="Text"`. Usually it is not required. Generally, ASP.NET now is considered as old if not deprecated. I'm surprised that you move one old (prehistorical) platform to another old platform. MVC and ASP Core are more popular today.